# Send serial break 'character' (wakeup call)

Tags: python, pyserial

I need to send a break 'character', wakeup call, through a serial port using Python, before sending any message request. I'm not sure the meaning of it and how to do it with Python. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `serial.Serial.send_break()` method.

([DOCS](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.send_break))